# jQuery.focus() function not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using the jQuery `focus()` method does not seem to work if I use it like this:

```
$('#<same_id_input>').focus();
```

When click in label I call a function to display a div with inputs inside and then I call the `focus()` on the `<input>` elements but it's not working.

I'm using:
Boostrap 3.3.7 + jQuery 3.1.1

```js
$('#optBusqueda .btn').click(function(){
    var radioSeleccionado=$(this).find(':radio').first();
    if(radioSeleccionado && radioSeleccionado.length>0){
        $('#divBuscarOcr').css("display","none");
        $('#divBuscarNombre').css("display","none");
        $('#divBuscarRfc').css("display","none");
        $('#divBuscarCurp').css("display","none");
        var idRadioSeleccionado=radioSeleccionado.attr('id');
        switch(idRadioSeleccionado){
            case "radioBuscarOcr":
                $('#divBuscarOcr').css("display","block");
                $('#txtBuscarOcr').focus();
                break;
            case "radioBuscarNombre":
                $('#divBuscarNombre').css("display","block");
                $('#divBuscarNombre').focus();
                break;
            case "radioBuscarRfc":
                $('#divBuscarRfc').css("display","block");
                $('#divBuscarRfc').focus();
                break;
            case "radioBuscarCurp":
                $('#divBuscarCurp').css("display","block");
                $('#divBuscarCurp').focus();
                break;
        }
        
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist"
    aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div id="panelBuscar" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading clearfix" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <!-- data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" -->
        <h4 class="panel-title pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
            href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-controls="collapseOne"> <i
            class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-search"></i> BUSCAR
          </a>
        </h4>
        <div id="optBusqueda" class="btn-group pull-right"
          data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary active" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Buscar por OCR"> <input
            name="options" id="radioBuscarOcr" type="radio" checked="true" />
            OCR
          </label> <label class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Buscar por Nombre"> <input name="options"
            id="radioBuscarNombre" type="radio" /> NOMBRE
          </label> <label class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Buscar por RFC"> <input name="options"
            id="radioBuscarRfc" type="radio" /> RFC
          </label> <label class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Buscar por CURP"> <input name="options"
            id="radioBuscarCurp" type="radio" /> CURP
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right" id="divMunicipioBuscar">
          <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <select id="txtNoMunicipioBuscar" name="txtNoMunicipioBuscar"
              th:attr="data-url=@{/municipios/get},data-emptyText='Seleccione municipio'"
              class="form-control populateSelect">
              <option value="">Seleccione municipio...</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in"
        role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 " id="divBuscarOcr">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input id="txtBuscarOcr" name="txtBuscarOcr" type="text"
                  class="form-control" placeholder="Ocr" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="divBuscarNombre" style="display: none;">
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input id="txtNombreBuscar" name="txtNombreBuscar" type="text"
                    class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input id="txtApPaternoBuscar" name="txtApPaternoBuscar"
                    type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido Pat." />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input id="txtApMaternoBuscar" name="txtApMaternoBuscar"
                    type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido Mat." />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="divBuscarRfc" style="display: none;">
              <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input id="txtBuscarRfc" name="txtBuscarRfc" type="text"
                    class="form-control" placeholder="Rfc" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="divBuscarCurp" style="display: none;">
              <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input id="txtBuscarCurp" name="txtBuscarCurp" type="text"
                    class="form-control" placeholder="Curp" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a id="btnBuscar" class="btn btn-default"
              onclick="busquedaCiudadano(this)"><i
              class="fa fa-lg fa-search"></i> Buscar</a>
          </div>
          <div id="divResultados"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my original example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snessnes/4xbLL81v/2/).

Comment: Pleas explain in more detail what the issue is. Also `$('"<same_id>')` you have mixed quotes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please see example, i can not edit post becose fiddlejs link

Comment: You can't edit this post?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is caused by using the Twitter Bootstrap toggle buttons. They probably call `focus()` in their own functionality, and this messes up the `focus()` you put on your element.

You can call `event.stopPropagation()` at the end, but this will completely stop the propagated event from happening and this will cause the toggle button not to appear as selected.

You could fix that by styling the selected state by yourself:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  $('#InputToFocus').focus();
  $(this).parent('.btn-group').find('.btn').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  return false; // Equivalent to preventDefault/stopPropagation
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label for="radio1" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" />
    Radio 1
  </label>
  <label for="radio2" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked />
    Radio 2
  </label>
</div>

<input id="InputToFocus" type="text">
```

As you can see, this enables the focus on the element and correctly styles the elements, though it's possible that there will be other consequences.

An alternative is to invoke your handler after the event has been handled. The easiest way to do that is by using `setTimeout()`.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  setTimeout(function() { // Hack to make sure the focus is called after the event has been handled
    $('#InputToFocus').focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label for="radio1" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" />
    Radio 1
  </label>
  <label for="radio2" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked />
    Radio 2
  </label>
</div>

<input id="InputToFocus" type="text">
```

Comment: @JorgeOmarSanchez then why you didn't hit Upvote & accept this answer

Comment: @basZero This question is tagged with [tag:twitter-bootstrap-3], so it makes sense that this won't work with Bootstrap 4.